# Installing MSM 2.1.4 onto EE 2.7.0 Getting blank wwhite screen

Tags: multi-site-manager

I have installed MSM 2.1.4 onto EE 2.7.0 and I can see the menu when I click on the site name (top-right) in the c-panel but when I click Edit Sites I get a blank screen.

without upgrate is there any solution

Answer (score 1):

Follow the guidelines from EE's [Troubleshooting -> Blank Pages](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/troubleshooting/general/blank_pages.html)